# Node.js spawn stdout to string for progress

Tags: node.js

How do I merge stdout chunks with dynamic console output (like git clone --progress).

e.g. stdout string with "working" \b (backspace)

Comment: Is `git` what you're actually trying to parse? There are git bindings for node that might have progress monitoring, though I don't know for sure.

Comment: Not. I need "parse" anything. I actually need "redirect" stdout to my web browser with websockets. But at this time if I'm add chunk to end of previous output. I recieve lots of data because every update "dynamic" output represents as a line.

Comment: can you show some code of what you have so far?

Comment: Here it is https://gist.github.com/927a2f3d938c9fbe26bb in file dream.log is what I need. Git is only example & script is only snippet.

Comment: I can run your code, then I can `cat temp/error.log` and the output looks fine. The carriage return works fine. You need to implement the carriage return on the browser side of your app. When you get a `\r` delete the last line you wrote.